# i am learning angular 2. i tried to show a picture with img tag and giving path in src but its showing image

Tags: angular2-template

I am using img tag in src i give path to the image but its not showing in browser and when i check inspect element and click on image path in new tab then its opening the same page in url localhost:4200/profile.jpg can you guys please help me. here is my code

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-xs-12">
        <div class="sidebar fixed">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="header/assets/profile.jpg" class="img img-responsive img-circle">
            </div>
            <div class="menu-bar">
                <ul class="menu-ul">
                    <li>
                        <a href=""> <i class="material-icons">face</i> My Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href=""> <i class="material-icons">perm_identity</i>  About Me</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href=""> <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i> Skills </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href=""> <i class="material-icons">work</i> Portfolio </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">  <i class="material-icons">exit_to_app</i> Logout</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-xs-12">
    </div>
</div>
```

and i have app/header/assets/profile.jpg and app/header/header.html file.

Comment: i try to make it in same folder but it also not working

Comment: finally i got the image by giving it full path src/app/header/assets/profile.jpg

Comment: but why cant we just get the image by using assets/profile.jpg ??

Comment: somehow i get the image but now cant apply on the image WTF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images by default should be referenced relative to the location of index.html. Try: src="app/header/assets/profile.jpg"

Comment: n if i wana apply some style on the image then bro ?

Comment: its not taking image classes of bootstrap

Comment: What do you mean? You can apply either a CSS class or the style attribute